# Use a CASE then CAST and then use the CAST value to do an Average

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL below it returns the build time for each of my builds but now I want to give me an average build time for the build. The BuildStartTime & BuildFinishTime are DateTime fields.

```
SELECT
Build_Quality.TeamProject,
DATEPART(year, BuildStartTime) AS Year,
DATENAME(month, BuildStartTime) AS Month,
--Get the Build Time
 CASE When buildname LIKE 'CI-%' then CAST(BuildFinishTime-BuildStartTime AS time(0)) END AS [CI Build Time],
 CASE When buildname LIKE '%AutoMerge%' then CAST(BuildFinishTime-BuildStartTime AS time(0)) END AS [Auto Merge Build Time],
 CASE When buildname NOT LIKE '%AutoMerge%' AND buildname NOT LIKE 'CI-%' then CAST(BuildFinishTime-BuildStartTime AS time(0)) END AS [Various Other Build Time]

FROM            
dbo.Build_Quality
GROUP BY
Build_Quality.TeamProject,
DATEPART(year, BuildStartTime),
DATENAME(month, BuildStartTime),
DATEPART(month, BuildStartTime),
BuildName,
BuildStartTime,
BuildFinishTime,
Build_Quality.BuildStatus

ORDER BY 
'Year',
DATEPART(month, BuildStartTime)
```

Comment: This query doesn't make sense. What is this `GROUP BY` clause ? Why so many columns?

Comment: please share the table structure and some data for reference..

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? I see no aggregate functions.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want in average? duration hour, duration day or what? but i think this would give you the idea:

```
WITH CTE AS (

        SELECT
            Build_Quality.TeamProject,
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, BuildStartTime, BuildFinishTime) AS DurationHours
        FROM            
            dbo.Build_Quality )

SELECT
        TeamProject
        , AVG(DurationHours)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY TeamProject
```